# Redirect based on text input case insensitive

Tags: javascript

new here and completely new to javascript.

I grabbed this bit of code, off this site I believe, I can't remember where.

```
 <form id='formName' name='formName' onsubmit='redirect();return false;'>
            <input type='text' id='userInput' name='userInput' value=''>
            <input type='submit' name='submit' value='Submit'>
        </form>

        <script type='text/javascript'>
        function redirect() {
            var input = document.getElementById('userInput').value;
            switch(input) {
                case 'keyword1':
                    window.location.replace('page1.html');
                    break;
                case 'keyword2':
                    window.location.replace('page2.html');
                    break;
                default:
                    window.location.replace('error.html');
                    break;
            }


        }
        </script>
```

as it is now it will only work if someone types 'keyword1' not 'Keyword1' or 'KEYWORD1' etc etc.  I'm sure it's simple to fix this but like I said, I'm new :-p

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: do you want it to accept the variations?

Answer (score 3):

Swap the input line for:

```
var input = document.getElementById('userInput').value.toLowerCase();
```

Comment: thanks I knew it was something like that just didn't know where it went.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the string to lowercase before doing the switch:

```
var input = document.getElementById('userInput').value.toLowerCase();
```